# Reading from process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() returns null when process launches

Tags: c#, excel, process, vsto

AIM: Launch a new process from the `VSTO` Excel Addin Project, which `ssh` to a unix machine using `putty(plink)` run some script over there and read the `StandardOutput` to get result.

---

Problem: `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` is returning empty string every time. but when same function is call from the console application it works perfectly. I think that there may be some authentication issue, since in previous case Excel is launching the process, and it later case user launches.

---

MY code:

```
 public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
      const String DOMAINS_COMMAND ="some_command";  
      string HOST = "some_host";
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            execute();

        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        public void execute()
        {
            try
            {                            
                Process p = new Process();
                ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();               
                ps.FileName = "plink"; 
                ps.Arguments = "-ssh " + HOST + " " + DOMAINS_COMMAND;
                ps.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                ps.RedirectStandardError = true;
                ps.UseShellExecute = false;
                ps.CreateNoWindow = true;                
                p.StartInfo = ps;   
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
                string rs = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show("value of result:"+rs);
            }

            catch
            { }


        }
        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```